# React Navigation: How to fake a history in Stack Navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I use https://reactnavigation.org/ and my app has a register process consisting of several screens:

- First, the user has to enter his first name ("FirstNameView")
- Second, the user has to enter his last name ("LastNameView")
- ...

If the user closes the app in the `LastNameView` and opens it later again, the app sends a request to the backend to fetch the current user data. Depending on this data, the user is navigated to the right screen via the `initialRouteName` property:

```
<MainStack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="LastNameView"
>...
```

I have a back button on every screen which does `navigation.goBack()`, which obviously not works if the user just opens the app again and I direct him to the right View without pushing other screens to it.

One approach that I could think of is removing the `navigation.goBack()` functionality and replacing it with `navigation.navigate("nameOfPreviousView")`. However, this has the drawback that native "back" functionality of e.g. Android would not work.

How can I handle a case like this? Can I somehow create a fake history with my `initialRouteName` approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can create previous route history without navigating there.
In NavigationContainer initialize initialState like

```
let initialState = initialRoute = {
  index: 1, // to load the second screen which is LastNameView
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'FirstNameView',
    },
    {
      name: 'LastNameView',
    },
  ],
};
```

Like
`<NavigationContainer initialState={initialState}> {/* ... */} </NavigationContainer>` 
To explore more about initialState check description here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#initialstate

Comment: Thanks a lot. I needed to refactor my code to make this work and it's not really nice now, but it works :-).